# Multiple citations in a singular context

Tags: multiple-citations

The following example:

```
Following \cite{XXX,YYY,ZZZ}, we use mean squared error...
```

Generates the text

> Following XXX (1974); YYY (1991); ZZZ (2021), we use mean squared error...

Is this the right way to cite multiple sources in a singular context? Or should I break it up and say `\cite{XXX}, \cite{YYY} and \cite{ZZZ}`?

Comment: Please tell us whether you're using a citation management package, say, `natbib`.

Comment: Yep I'm using `natbib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this query and my answer are more about English language syntax than about LaTeX, bibtex, or biblatex.

With "textual" citation call-outs, it's important to generate a citation call-out that could be read out loud "as is", i.e., without the reader having to spend time figuring out where in the sentence a pause -- or a lack thereof -- should be thrown in. The answer to the OP's question tends to come down to this:

- If XXX, YYY, and ZZZ are by 3 separate authors (or author groups), it's best to have three separate `\citet` instructions:

  ```
  As argued by \citet{XXX}, \citet{YYY}, and \citet{ZZZ}, \dots
  ```
- Conversely, if XXX, YYY, and ZZZ are all by the author(s), it's natural to have a single `\citet` instruction:

  ```
  As argued by \citet{XXX,YYY,ZZZ}, \dots
  ```
- Finally, if 2 of the 3 are by the same author(s), it's natural to write

  ```
  As argued by \citet{XXX,ZZZ} and \citet{YYY}, \dots
  ```

Let me note once more that these "rules" are *not* set in stone. For sure, depending on the situation, it can be entirely ok to deviate from these rules.

Comment: I fully support @Micos answer and would add that it also depends on the scientific field/discipline you're working in. In my experience almost every field has its own rules...